# Array dentro do foreach retorna última coluna do banco

Tags: php

O problema é que dessa forma, retorne apenas a última coluna do banco de dados

```
public function Acentos ( $string ) {

   $Acentos = $this->SelectDados(
       "*",
       "table",
       "",
       array ()
   );

   foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

       $table = array (

          $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome'] )

        );

    }

    return strtr ( $string, $table );
}
```

Eu tentei fazer assim

```
$Dados = array ();

foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

    $table = array (

       $Dados[] = $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $Dados[] = $List['nome'] )

    );

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está declarando uma nova  array  toda vez que passa pelo  foreach,  tenta usar um array push exemplo

```
public function Acentos ( $string ) {

   $table = array();
   $Acentos = $this->SelectDados(
       "*",
       "table",
       "",
       array ()
   );

   foreach ( $Acentos as $List ) {

       array_push($table,

          $List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome'] )

        );

    }

    return strtr ( $string, $table );
}
```

> Referências

array_push  > https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php

array  > https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Escopos > https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: `Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' `
`$List['slug'] => utf8_encode ( $List['nome'] )`